# Setting up firebase in android studio gives error

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am currently working on an app in android studio, and i need some simple server implementation to log some data. I've run through the setup tutorial on the firebase website: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html, but when i try to run the app it gives me this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I figured that maybe it has something to do with the .jar file that i had to place into my libs folder, or maybe i have the wrong jdk?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are you implementing it? Maven, Gradle, or a jar?

Comment: The most likely reason is that you're including too many libraries, which leads to a dex file becoming too big. If that is the cause *and* you are using Google Play Services, follow the instructions in "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" on https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your gradle. This will solve the issue for me.

```
dexOptions{
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```